# dask: What does memory_limit control?

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

In dask's LocalCluster, there is a parameter `memory_limit`.  I can't find in the documentation (https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/worker.html#memory-management) details about whether the limit is per worker, per thread, or for the whole cluster.  This is probably at least in part because I have trouble following how keywords are passed around.

For example, in this code:

```py
cluster = LocalCluster(n_workers=2,
                       threads_per_worker=4,
                       memory_target_fraction=0.95,
                       memory_limit='32GB')
```

will that be 32 GB for each worker?  For both workers together?  Or for each thread?

My question is motivated partly by running a `LocalCluster` with `n_workers=1` and `memory_limit=32GB`, but it gets killed by the Slurm Out-Of-Memory killer for using too much memory.

Comment: The link you posted says explicitly that it's a per worker limit `$ dask-worker tcp://scheduler:port --memory-limit="4 GiB"  # four gigabytes per worker process.` And you get the process killed if you reach 95% of RAM usage.

Comment: The documentation you've linked to talks about [command-line options for dask-worker](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/setup/cli.html?highlight=memory_limit#dask-worker).

Your code snippet uses the keyword argument `memory_limit` which I believe is different. You're also right about this not being in the [list of parameters for LocalCluster](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/setup/single-distributed.html#localcluster). FWIW, looks like this keyword argument sets the memory limit for the whole cluter. Using `client = Client(cluster); client` shows each worker having 16GB total memory

Comment: rpanai, thanks for pointing that out - you're right, that comment suggests that the memory limit is per-worker, but Pavithra's comment suggests that comment doesn't apply to the keyword argument - hence my confusion.  Also, I believe the `memory_target_fraction` is not the fraction at which tasks are killed; that is `distributed.workers.memory.terminate` (which is not accessible as a keyword argument)

Comment: The second part of your comment, around `memory_target_fraction` isn't directly related to this question. I'd suggest opening a separate issue for that one :)

Comment: FYI, I've created an issue here: https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/8224, I'll share an answer to this question after confirmation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `memory_limit` keyword argument to LocalCluster sets the limit per worker.

Related documentaion: https://github.com/dask/distributed/blob/7bf884b941363242c3884b598205c75373287190/distributed/deploy/local.py#L76-L78

Note, if the memory_limit given is greater than the available memory, the total available memory will be set for each worker. This behavior hasn't been documented yet, but a relevant issue is here: https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/8224

Screenshot of cluster with code:

```
from dask.distributed import LocalCluster, Client
cluster = LocalCluster(n_workers=2,
                       threads_per_worker=4,
                       memory_target_fraction=0.95,
                       memory_limit='8GB')
client = Client(cluster)
client
```

[image]